# Movie about a teenage boy who commits vigilantism, the twist is his perception is skewed

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to find a movie I watched on Netflix a few years ago. There was teenager in a largish city who started to get involved in vigilantism (stopping muggings, saving girls in dark alleys, nothing fantastic like Batman or Green arrow). I remember he 'disguised' himself with black eye makeup pulled down from his eyes.

There was a twist to the movie however where in the boys perception was skewed; it turns out due to his abusive past he was perceiving every day normal interactions as hostility directed at the "weaker target". I remember one scene where you see a mother chiding her child and a couple having a normal disagreement, then through the protagonists perception you see the mother abusively screaming at her child and the boyfriend raising his fist to hit the girl.

Additionally, there may have been a female detective investigating the boy, but also had a close personal bond with him from either before or very close to after the first act of vigilantism we see in the movie.

Other details

- It was set in a large city,
- It was relatively recent, made within the last decade at least
- It was in English, most likely made in the US
- It seems like the title played on a comic book character somehow

Comment: According to the wikipedia summary, he kills the mugger. I'm not sure that still counts as low-grade vigilantism.

Comment: @stannius I wasn't sure how to express the intent -- Not that he doesn't kill, but more that he isn't say, going after the obviously criminal but hard to prosecute mob bosses (think boondock saints), but instead goes after the actual perpetrators of violence.

Comment: Low level? Granted, grade is sort of a synonym for level. Anyways the question would be fine without either adjective.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Possibly [***Boy Wonder***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1456060/) (2010)

[image]

> A traumatized boy grows into a shy, determined teenager who patrols the mean streets of New York City, helping those in need and dishing out severe punishment to remorseless thugs.

> While riding the train, Sean encounters a homeless man verbally harassing a Chinese family and the passengers of the train. He tells the family to leave the car before putting on **face paint** and brutally beating the man with brass knuckles.
>
> As Sean walks down the street, he sees scenes of domestic violence that apparently revert to gentle arguments after he passes by.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_Wonder_(film))</sup>

Comment: See, now you're getting the hang of it. :P